# Desktop Background is blank

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, desktop

I change my background in system preferences and it says my background is a picture, but my desktop is still a blank gray. How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7.2

Comment: Are you using a Thunderbolt Display? Mine has been turning off randomly, and after that the desktop picture has sometimes been replaced with a solid gray background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try opening Terminal, type `killall Dock` and press return. Dock controls the desktop background in Lion.

If it's still grey after that, try `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop` then `killall Dock`